# Do we have a tag for vision or eyesight?

Tags: discussion, tags

I was looking at [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/87112/) and found the tags [safety] to be a bit lacking. Do we not have any tags like [eyesight] or [vision] ? It seems questions about eyesight and vision are frequent. Am I missing an existing tag?

Comment: What Jamiec said; I now added more appropriate tags for the time being.

Comment: I personally don't think that such a tag would be useful, but if enough people think otherwise, I have nothing to add.

Comment: *If* a tag, or pair of tags are created, please MAKE SURE to properly edit their information. The last thing we want are questions about eyesight/vision that are not aviation related, just because we have tags. It has happened before. There is nothing wrong with a question about color-blindness, for instance, and it's effect and affect, on flying and obtaining licenses, but, for instance, _why do ophthalmologists use phoroptors?_ is not, unless directly related to flying.

Comment: And the answer is, they don't, optometrist's do. :)

Answer (score 1):

Tags are created by [users with enough reputation](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags), and as such if nobody has ever created the tag it will not exist.

You can also [search through](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/tags) the existing tags to see if one already exists.

Comment: I could add the tag myself and go put it in all those questions. I am hesitating because of what @Federico said. Also, do tag edits still bump questions? If so. I won't do this

Comment: @Abdullah Yes tag edits bump the question and I also agree with Federico.